# How to convert null to default(float) or 0

Tags: c#

I am trying to get float values as input and if a value is skipped to just set it to 0 but since the skip sets it to null I get an exception. So, I tried using the "??" operator like this :

```
float speed = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine()) ?? default(float);
```

or

```
float speed = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine()) ?? 0;
```

But I get an error :

> error CS0019: Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'float' and 'int'

How would I write the equivalent of this : `float y = x ?? 0;`

```
public static void CalculateDistanceTimeSpeed()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Find distance/speed/time based on any of the two.");
    Console.WriteLine("Enter two of the three requirements");
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter speed in km/h (Enter 0 if unkown)");
    float speed = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter distance in km (Enter 0 if unkown)");
    float distance = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter time in hour/s (Enter 0 if unkown)");
    float time = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine(distance, speed, time);

    if (speed == 0)
    {
        speed = distance / time;
        speed.ToString("0.##");

        Console.WriteLine("Determined Average speed : {1}km/h, based on distance: {0}km and time: {2}hrs.", distance, speed, time);
    }

    else if (distance == 0)
    {
        distance = time / speed;
        distance.ToString("0.##");

        Console.WriteLine("Determined distance traveled : {0}km, based on speed: {1}km/h and time: {2}hrs.", distance, speed, time);

    }

    else
    {
        time = distance / speed;
        time.ToString("0.##");

        Console.WriteLine("Determined time traveled: {2}hrs, based on speed: {1}km/h for distance: {0}km.", distance, speed, time);
    }
```

Comment: I see no `null` anywhere here.

Comment: Use float.TryParse.

Comment: First search why are you getting this error? Because data type is not nullable. So you can check how to make it nullable.

Answer (score 4):

`Convert.ToSingle()` will throw an exception if the format is unknown, it never returns null. You should use `Single.TryParse()` to easily check if the result is proper.

```
float speed;
if (!Single.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out speed))
    speed = 0f;
```

Also note that these methods will use the current locale so they might accept input differently on different locales. Make sure you specify the proper locale if input is expected with a certain locale (e.g. decimal separators)

Answer (score 2):

Just to answer your question:

> How would I write the equivalent of this : float y = x ?? 0

```
float? x = 10f;
float y = x ?? 0f;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `0f` to tell the compiler your 0 is a `float` not an `int`.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx) for details.

Comment: But he can't use the null-coalescing operator on value types, only on types that can be null (reference types).

Comment: His question was "How would I write the equivalent of this : float y = x ?? 0;"

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the null coalescing operator with value types (except [nullable types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)), only with reference types that can be `null`. However, you could use this one-liner:

```
float speed =  Single.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out speed) ? speed : default(float);
```

Comment: That's not true, you can use the null coalescing operator with nullable types, which are also value types.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
Since `Convert.ToSingle()` returns `float` and not `float?` the result is never `null`.

Answer (score 0):

There was already posted valid answers, but I guess it is appropriate to give some background why this error `error CS0019: Operator ??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'float' and 'int'` comes up.

In C# we have reference types and value types. The difference is

> Variables of reference types store references to their data (objects), while variables of value types directly contain their data.

As stated in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx).

Since `float`, `int` and [a couple more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfft1t3c.aspx) types are in fact value types, it becomes obvious why you can't use [null-coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms173224.aspx) with those types. They simply can't be `null`, because they are not storing any reference (which could be `null`), but value itself.

Answer (score 0):

That worked. Thanks guys. Here is the solution that worked for me, in case someone is curious.

```
public static void CalculateDistanceTimeSpeed()
{
    float speed;
    float distance;
    float time;

    Console.WriteLine("Find distance/speed/time based on any of the two.");
    Console.WriteLine("Enter two of the three requirements");
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter speed in km/h");
    if (!Single.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out speed))
        speed = 0f;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter distance in km");
    if (!Single.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out distance))
        distance = 0f;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter time in hour/s");
    if (!Single.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out time))
        time = 0f;

    if (speed == 0f)
    {
        speed = distance / time;
        Console.WriteLine("Required average Speed : {1}km/h for distance {0}km and time {2}hrs.", distance, speed.ToString("0.##"), time);
    }

    else if (distance == 0f)
    {
        distance = speed * time;
        Console.WriteLine("Distance traveled : {0}km at speed {1}km/h for {2}hrs.", distance.ToString("0.##"), speed, time);

    }

    else
    {
        time = distance / speed;
        Console.WriteLine("Travel time: {2}hrs with speed {1}km/h for distance {0}km.", distance, speed, time.ToString("0.##"));
    } 

    // add mph conversion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

`float speed = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine() ?? "0");`